# Orchard Workflow 1.7

Tags: workflow, orchardcms

I have downloaded the latest upcoming 1.7 version and I tried to understand how workflow works and how it can be extended.

First question is: is there some documentation about it?
I found something but not so detailed on how to extend workflow with my features.

For now this is what I cannot figure out myself inspecting the existing code:

How can I assign a custom icon to my custom action (like the envelope in send mail) both on canvas and in toolbox?
I have tried providing a css class with same name and a resource (in a different module), the action works but it shows default icon.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. No
2. Look at the stylesheets in the module. You'll see that the image is being defined inline, from the stylesheet, as a background image, for each activity. You may of course use an external image, or reproduce that pattern of including it inline.